# Clang generating warning "method '-init' not found" for very simple class

Tags: objective-c, clang

I just came across [Clang/LLVM today](http://clang.llvm.org/), and decided to try it out.

My system is FreeBSD8.1-Release.
The default system compiler is GCC4.2.1, which is what I have been using to compile my Objective-C project up until now.

I'm playing around with the Static Analyzer, and would like to know how to eliminate one of the warnings that is being generated.

*MyClass.h*

```
#import <objc/Object.h>

@interface MyClass: Object {
}

-(MyClass*) init;

@end
```

*MyClass.m*

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

-(MyClass*) init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
                // do stuff
        }
        return self;
}

@end
```

The warning:

```
%clang --analyze MyClass.m
MyClass.m:7:9: warning: method '-init' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
        self = [super init];
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 diagnostic generated.
```

I take it that the analyzer does not know how to determine *super*'s type (*Object*, in this case). Is there any way to eliminate this warning (other than by suppression)? I looked into casting *super*, but it looks like that is not allowed.

Thanks!
Max

---

**Update**

Thanks to Dave and bbum for pointing me in the right direction for eliminating the warning. Now I'm trying to figure out why the warning occurs in the first place.

If anyone has any ideas or leads, I love the hear them.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: The warning is simple, it's telling you that `super` does not have an `init` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- You should be inheriting from `NSObject`, not `Object`.
- Your `init` method should return `id`, not `MyClass*`.

Comment: There are still a couple of runtime variants that use `Object` as the base class.  Since OP is on a non-Mac OS X system, that may be in play.  But, even then, moving to `NSObject` ASAP is generally the right answer.

Comment: @bbum: ha, i totally missed the FreeBSD bit.

Comment: Thanks for the input Dave. I installed GNUstep (AppKit/Cocoa implementation), and Clang no longer raises the complaint I described above.

Comment: @maxenglander: in GNUstep, you would also use NSObject not Object

Answer (score 0):

The warning is saying that it does not know of *any* method named `-init` at all in scope at that point. You need to import a header file that declares `-init`, which is probably Foundation.h or something, depending on what system you're using.